# Adding additional criteria in if statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, timestamp

Struggling with these & feel like I've put together all the possible combinations, just not fully understanding.

I have this amazing script that records the timestamp when a checkbox turns true in the same row (just a different column).

I am trying to in essence, add another level to it, where I can set the status for a DIFFERENT column, and then record a timestamp for that as well.

In other words, this is the working script (one if):

```
    function onEdit(e) {
      const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    
    
    
      if (sheet.getName() !== 'TEST SHEET'
        || sheet.getRange('P' + e.range.rowStart).getValue() !== 'In Progress') {
        return;
      }
      sheet.getRange('AK' + e.range.rowStart)
        .setValue(new Date())
        .setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
}
```

I'm trying to make it something like:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();



  if (sheet.getName() !== 'TEST SHEET'
    || sheet.getRange('P' + e.range.rowStart).getValue() !== 'In Progress') {
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRange('AK' + e.range.rowStart)
    .setValue(new Date())
    .setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');

    
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'TEST SHEET'
    || sheet.getRange('P' + e.range.rowStart).getValue() !== 'Completed') {
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRange('AL' + e.range.rowStart)
    .setValue(new Date())
    .setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
    
}
```

Doing some research, seems like nothing would work after "return".. I tried adding in the fields before, and did some testing moving everything around but still now luck.

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Comment: Provide debugging information. See execution logs in script editor: It should show why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add a parameter for each value that may change (the range to set, and the value to compare against), then call that function twice.

```
function tryInsertDate(e, rangeToSet, val) {
    const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    if (
        sheet.getName() !== 'TEST SHEET'
        || sheet.getRange('P' + e.range.rowStart).getValue() !== val
    ) {
        return;
    }
    sheet.getRange(rangeToSet + e.range.rowStart)
        .setValue(new Date())
        .setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
}
function onEdit(e) {
    tryInsertDate(e, 'AK', 'In Progress');
    tryInsertDate(e, 'AL', 'Completed');
}
```

If those are states, you could name the parameter `state` to be more precise.

Comment: `onEdit` is a triggered function: If a edit happens in a sheet, the function named `onEdit` is automatically called with the event object `e`. So, you should probably rename your refactored function to something else and enclose the two function calls in another function named ``onEdit``

Comment: @TheMaster it just says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined" when I try to run, regarding your other comment.

Comment: @AnthonyMadle Did you pass the parameter along in the `onEdit` function? It sounds like you're doing something like `tryInsertDate()` instead of `tryInsertDate(e, 'AK', 'In Progress')` (or maybe you're not defining a parameter for `onEdit`)

Comment: @AnthonyMadle See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-ca You can't call onEdit directly. You need to make a edit. The updated script above should work. (But I think your script in question should also work)

Comment: I thought the problem with the script in the question was that `return` would terminate the whole function, instead of possibly going on to check whether the `AL` section needs a timestamp. Using separate functions would mean that `return` inside one wouldn't break the other. (Another option is to iterate over an array of ranges / values to check inside `onEdit`)

Comment: @TheMaster this is amazing - working like a charm.  I don't fully understand how to fix mine - wish I could figure that out. Going to spend some more time on it, but nice to see how you were able to accomplish.  Kudos!!

Comment: @CertainPerformance based on my reading, this is what I thought too - I just was having trouble tweaking (I'm very new to this).  Makes much more sense though now, great input

Comment: @CertainPerformance There's no explanation for why you suggested those changes in the answer. You're right. I completely missed that the `if` condition referred to different strings. Your answer would benefit greatly, if you added that explanation explicitly in the answer itself.